Apache Hop Web behind Reverse Proxy (Nginx)
Has anyone successfully gotten Apache Hop running using a web server as a reverse proxy (preferably Nginx)? I've hacked at it for a bit using a range of standard tricks and gleanings from various pages with no luck. My current configuration renders the initial screen properly but fails with any interaction (session issue?) with a 'The application terminated unexpectedly.' error. Note: it appears that Hop Web is am Eclipse RAP/RWT Jetty application.
Here's my relevant nginx configuration:
    upstream @hop-web {
      server hop-cluster-web.hop-cluster:8080;
    }
    server {
        listen 8080;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        port_in_redirect off;
        server_name xxxxxx;
        root xxxxx;
      
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxxx;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxxx;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2;
    
    
        location /hop-server/rwt-resources {
                proxy_pass http://hop-cluster-web.hop-cluster:8080/rwt-resources;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   
                proxy_cookie_path /rwt-resources /hop-server/rwt-resources;
        }
    
        location ~ ^/hop-server/ui(/.*)?$ {
                proxy_pass http://hop-cluster-web.hop-cluster:8080/ui$1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                
                proxy_cookie_path /ui /hop-server/ui;
        }
    
        # Main proxy pass to load balancer for /hop-server
        location /hop-server/ {
                proxy_pass http://@hop-web;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        
                proxy_cookie_path / /hop-server/;
        }
}

